# Is there any special jQuery that would execute two different set of codes for one element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, state, jquery-events

I have [code](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudObserver/CloudObserverInstaller/htdocs/index.html?r=989) that lets me to show an element on click of one element and hide it on click of another. [Code](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudObserver/CloudObserverInstaller/htdocs/index.html?r=989) looks like:

```
      $('.downloads').hide()
      $('.downloads').css({visibility:'visible'})
      var Dshow=false;                     
      $('.allLink').click(function() {     
      if(!Dshow){
          Dshow=true;
          $(".downloads").fadeIn("fast");
           $('#footer2').html($('#footer1').html()); 
           $('#footer1').html('');}
           
    });
     $('.hideAllLink').click(function() {
     if(!!Dshow){
   Dshow=false;
           $(".downloads").fadeOut("fast");
           $('#footer1').html($('#footer2').html());
           $('#footer2').html('');}
    });
```

I want  `$('.allLink').click(function()` to have 2 states - on first click it shall show ".downloads" and on second click hide.

How to do such thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a toggler: Use of jQuery toggle function

Use

```
$( "#idofthebutton" ).toggle(

                function() {
                    /// hide the link
                   $(".downloads").fadeOut("fast");
                }, function() {
                    ///show the link
                 $(".downloads").fadeIn("fast");
                }

   );
```

This will work automatically to hide and show the links....

**Note:** In this case keep the links visible at first place. If you don't want that then change the order of the functions inside the .toggle

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). This method will hide element if it's visible, or make it visible if it's hidden.

```
$('.allLink').click(function()) {
    $('.downloads').toggle();
}
```